# MYSQL Stored Procedure Variables in While loop

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Ok this may be super simple but I cannot seem to find an answer.
I am currently trying to clean up some storeod procedures that use a bunch of select statements with variables that only increment in number such as. id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, id7 and id8. Instead of calling upwards of 24 statements in a row, I would like to cut the stored procedure down to just a few lines.

Now please excuse me if syntax is way off, not a MySQL programmer by trade.

In my normal languages I would do a while loop with a the variable and the control attached such as.

```
while x <= count do

 select * from table where col = id[x];

 SET x = x + 1;


end;
```

what is the proper way to attach the control to the end of the variable? is this possible in a stored procedure at all? Select statements are a little more than the one shown but if I can do a simple one like that it will work for the rest of the statement.

Code currently used, this is only part of the code. I just posting one with the 3 different select statements. Currently using 3 different basic select into statements. If I can somehow combine all 3 into 1 statement would be amazing but I am newer to MySQL, maybe given some more time?
 
`if (licount <=2 ) then      /* 2 Stations */ 
    select gen_idx into gen_idx1 from j_final_results where line=pline and station=1 and type_result=1 order by ID desc limit 1;
    select gen_idx into gen_idx2 from j_final_results where line=pline and station=2 and type_result=1 order by ID desc limit 1;
    set gen_idx3=0;
    set gen_idx4=0;
    set gen_idx5=0;
    set gen_idx6=0;
    set gen_idx7=0;
    set gen_idx8=0;
    select scan_lbl into serial1 from j_final_results where line=pline and station=1 and type_result=1 order by ID desc limit 1;
    select scan_lbl into serial2 from j_final_results where line=pline and station=2 and type_result=1 order by ID desc limit 1;
    set serial3='';
    set serial4='';
    set serial5='';
    set serial6='';
    set serial7='';
    set serial8='';
    select type_result into type1 from j_final_results where line=pline and station=1 order by ID desc limit 1;
    select type_result into type2 from j_final_results where line=pline and station=2 order by   ID desc limit 1;
    set type3=0;
    set type4=0;
    set type5=0;
    set type6=0;
    set type7=0;
    set type8=0;`

Comment: You can do soemthing similar in a procedure,whats the problem?

Comment: I am just trying ot figure out the correct way to do id[x]? if that is the way than awesome.

Comment: It would help if you could post the long SP you have.

Comment: updated with one section of code currently used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some dynamic code creation, my preferred method would look something like this:

```
WHILE X <= COUNT DO


    SET @sql = CONCAT('select * from table where col = id',X);
    PREPARE runme FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE runme;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE runme;

    SET X = X + 1;


END;
```

You can also put a ? in the @sql string and pass X in with USING - see here:[sql-syntax-prepared-statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: I think this will work for what I need, I have one question though. I have some varibles that get passed into the procedure. I need to use that variable inside the statement too. The variable is shown above as 'pline'. How do i use this inside the prepared statement? I also have a problem on the id[x] part as it keeps saying variable does not exist.

Comment: I believe I figured it out. I appreciate the help, this worked nicely!

Comment: Glad it worked out, sorry I did not get back sooner, had to go off-line.